# What is an exemplar problem and solution for learning shared memory, distributed memory, and/or GPU programming?

Tags: c, cuda, openmp, mpi, opencl

We are looking for exemplar problems and codes that will run on any or all of shared memory, distributed memory, and GPGPU architectures. The reference platform we are using is LittleFe (littlefe.net), an open-design, low cost educational cluster currently with six dual core CPUs, each with an nVidia chipset.

These problems and solutions will be good for teaching parallelism to any newbie by providing working examples and opportunities to roll up your sleeves and code. Stackoverflow experts have good insight and are likely to have some favorites.

Calculating area under a curve is interesting, simple and easy to understand, but there are bound to be ones that are just as easily expressed and chock full of opportunities to practice and learn.

Hybrid examples using more than one of the memory architectures are most desirable, and reflective of where parallel programming seems to be trending.

On LittleFe we have predominantly been using three applications. The first is an analysis of optimal targets on a dartboard which is highly parallel with little communication overhead. The second is Conway's game of life which is a typical of problems sharing boundary conditions. It has a moderate communication overhead. The third is an n-body model of galaxy formation which requires heavy communication overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory) contains a detailed analysis of the implementation of matrix multiplication on a GPU. That seems to be the staple "hello world" example for learning GPU programing.

Furthermore, the CUDA SDK contains tens of other well explained examples of GPU programming in CUDA and OpenCL. My favorite is the [colliding balls example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/particles). (a demo with a few thousands of balls colliding in real time)

### Update:

The CUDA samples are not packaged with the Toolkit anymore. Instead you can find them on [GitHub](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master).

Comment: Sweet, ever since "Sing along with Mitch", folk like the bouncing ball, and perhaps it can be modified to demonstrate the ideal gas law.

Answer (score 1):

Two of my favorites are numerical integeration and finding prime numbers. For the first we code the midpoint rectangle rule on the function f(x) = 4.0 / (1.0 + x*x). Integration of the function between 0 and 1 give an approximation of the constant pi, which makes checking the correctness of the answer easy. The parallelism is across the range of the integration (computing the areas of rectangles).

For the second, we input an integer range and then identify and save the prime numbers in that range. We use a brute force division of values by all possible factors; if any divisors are found that are not 1 or the number, then the value is composite. If a prime is found, count it and store in a shared array. The parallelism is dividing up the range since testing for primality of N is independent of testing M. There is some trickiness needed to share the prime store between threads or to gather distributed parital answers.

These are very basic and simple problems to solve, which allows students to focus on the parallel implementation and not so much on the computation involved.

Comment: Thanks Clay. I knew my favorite thread monkey would have some great suggestions.

Comment: Clay, Andrew Fitz Gibbon, and I met to work on ACM tech pack 2 for parallel programming at the end of the Petascale Institute at which Fitz and I were teaching. I used a varient of this directly tied to the equation of the unit circle, x^2 + y^2 = 1, solving for y gives y=sqrt(1-x^2). Taking the area under it from -1 to 1 gives the area of a semicircle, namely pi/2. I used this at the Petascale Institute to teach mpi point to point communication and also as an example of the Berkeley Map-Reduce motif. Others extended my serial version of this code to teach both OpenMP and Cuda.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more complex but easy example problems is the BLAS routine sgemm or dgemm (C = alpha * A x B + beta * C) where A, B, C are matrices of valid sizes and alpha and beta are scalars. The types may be single precision floating point (sgemm) or double precision floating point (dgemm).

The implementation of this simple routine on different platforms and architectures teaches some insights about the functionality and working principles. For more details on BLAS and the ?gemm routine have a look to http://www.netlib.org/blas.

You need only to pay attention that for a double precision implementation on the GPU the GPU needs to have double precision capabilities.

Comment: This is great suggestion. Thanks. It also naturally leads into an investigation/discussion of BLAS and other numerical libraries. A second jumping off point is discussing error and that going from single to double precision and geting the same result is not a sufficient way to verify the numerical stability of an algorithm